# POST to a REST URL directly from ftp

Tags: c#

I would like to download a file from a FTP and directly POST to a REST URL without having to save in a temp folder, which I am currently doing. Works great, but not what I want to do. When I take a file directly from the FTP, the `File.OpenRead` takes not only the FTP path

> ftp://xxxx.xxxxxx.xxx/

but it adds the project path

> C://myProject/ProjectName

in front of it, thus causing a

> The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.

Where am I going wrong?

```
using(var client = new WebClient())
{
    client.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/octet-stream");

    using(var filestream = File.OpenRead(FTP_Path + FTP_filename))
    using(var requestStream = client.OpenWrite(new Uri(fileUploadUrl), "POST"))
    {
        filestream.CopyTo(requestStream);
    }
}
```

Comment: `File.OpenRead` is specifically looking for a location on your local host.  You'll need to either use your `WebClient` that you initialized as `client` or initalize a second WebClient to access the remote location.

Comment: @Blaine - depending on how large is the file, - could you use https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpcontent.readasbytearrayasync - ReadAsByteArrayAsync () or ReadAsStreamAsync() ?

Comment: Changing File.OpenRead to client fixes the error, however since SSL is enabled, this direction does not work with webclient. Is there another way to go from FTP to a REST call?